# NotesUIWorkspace.EditDocument sometimes returns nothing

Tags: vba, excel, lotus-notes

I am writing a vba sub that allows user to send a Lotus Notes email according to the contents in an excel spreadsheet.

The following sub sometimes runs without problems but sometimes failed near the end

```
Set uiDoc = uiws.EditDocument(True, oDoc)
```

where the Lotus Notes application UI apparently opened up a new mail for editing, but the variable `uiDoc` did not receive a `NotesUIDocument` instance.

The problem seems random to me, and I am now getting around this by manually reruning the sub several times until it suceeds.

How could I ensure `uiDoc` get the instance?

```
Public Sub SendEmail( _
    Ws As Worksheet, _
    Optional Commit As Boolean = False, _
    Optional Delim As String = "<Delim>")

    ' Notes session
    Dim oSess As Object
    Set oSess = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")


    ' Notes database
    Dim oDB As Object
    Set oDB = oSess.GETDATABASE("", "")
    If Not oDB.IsOpen Then
        oDB.OPENMAIL
    End If


    ' Notes documment
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Set oDoc = oDB.CREATEDOCUMENT

    oDoc.Subject = Ws.Range("Subject").Value

    Dim VSendTo As Variant
    VSendTo = Split(Ws.Range("Send_To").Value, ",")
    oDoc.sendto = VSendTo

    Dim VCCTo As Variant
    VCCTo = Split(Ws.Range("CC_To").Value, ",")
    oDoc.copyto = VCCTo

    Dim oItem As Object
    Set oItem = oDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("BODY")


    ' Notes UI document
    Dim uiws As Object
    Set uiws = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")

    Dim uiDoc As Object
    ' uiDoc should receive a NotesUIDocument if successful
    Set uiDoc = uiws.EditDocument(True, oDoc)


    ' Body
    DoEvents

    Call uiDoc.GOTOFIELD("Body")

    ' ** Omitted **

Exit Sub
```

Documentation on NotesUIWorkspace class:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESUIWORKSPACE_CLASS.html

I am using Lotus Notes Release 8.5.2

Comment: It's been ages since I have worked with LN. Before executing the line `Set uiDoc = uiws.EditDocument(True, oDoc)` check if `uiws` is not nothing and returns a valid object.

Comment: I found that `uiws` is not nothing, and if i run this single command `Set uiDoc = uiws.EditDocument(True, oDoc)` again in vba debug mode after waiting some time there is a chance it can run.

Comment: In that case you need to add `DoEvents` before `Set uiDoc = uiws.EditDocument(True, oDoc)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout You should post your two comments as an answer, so that it can be upvoted.

Comment: after adding `DoEvents` before Set `uiDoc = uiws.EditDocument(True, oDoc)` uiDoc still sometimes fails to receive an instance (again, when the error occured the NotesUIWorkspace instance was there and the loutus notes app had responded by recreating a new email tab)

Comment: Just a note here: the Lotus Notes Automation Classes (OLE classes, late binding, "Notes.NotesSession", "Notes.NotesUIWorkspace") have been deprecated for nearly 14 years (since the release of R5.0.2c). They were always somewhat buggy and crashy, and are only in the product anymore at all because of IBM/Lotus's obsession with perpetual backwards compatibility for existing working code. The supported methods are the back-end-only Domino COM classes ("Lotus.NotesSession").

Comment: I decided to give up the "Front End" approach (as it involves the use of `NotesUIDocument`) and send [MIME email](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/bpmpblog.nsf/dx/creating-a-mime-email-with-attachment?opendocument&comments) instead.